# Multiple group_by with dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

There is a lot of questions about it on this forum but I could not do it. I got a dataframe with a bunch of categrocial variables (class factor). I got a target column (1 or 0). I want to compute the frequency of 1's within each level of the categorical variables. I want to do those 3 group_by computations in once.

```
library(dplyr)

# Build the toy dataset
target  = sample(x = c(0,1),size = 100,replace = T)
cat1 = sample(x = c("a","b","c"),size = 100,replace = T)
cat2 = sample(x = c("x","y","z"),size = 100,replace = T)
cat3 = sample(x = c("T","U","V"),size = 100,replace = T)
df = data.frame(target,cat1,cat2,cat3)

# How to do those 3 group_by computations in once knowing that in reality I got thousands of those categorical columns?
df %>%
  group_by(cat1) %>%
  summarise(statistics = mean(target))

df %>%
  group_by(cat2) %>%
  summarise(statistics = mean(target))

df %>%
  group_by(cat3) %>%
  summarise(statistics = mean(target))
```

Comment: `group_by(starts_with("cat"))`?

Comment: Try `tidyr::gather(df, k,val, -target) %>% group_by(k,val) %>% summarise(stats=mean(target))`

Comment: @ A. Suliman , wow thks u. It works great!

Comment: @Jaap Does that work? `group_by` doesn't support `vars` argument I think.

Comment: No the group_by(strats... do not work

Comment: @RonakShah I expected it to work, but apparently not. You might it to work with something like `!!!` from `rlang`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this code can help you:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(cat1,cat2,cat3) %>%
  summarise(statistics = mean(target)) %>% arrange(cat1,cat2)
```